# ASP.NET Updating without full publish?

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, I tried searching.

Anyhow, is it possible to update a publised site without the need to do a full publish.

Say for example you fixed a bug in one single file, is this possible?

any work arounds, advice etc?

**Darknight**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming V2+ of the .Net framework :

If you're publishing a website you can just upload the files that you changed, via FTP say as long as the site was published with 'Allow this precompiled site to be updatable' when you did the publish (or in the property pages of the website in VS2008).

This isn't quite the case with web applications, which will need you to deploy any changed assemblies again. Your aspx and ascx files, however can be reuploaded, obviously its best not to do this incase you break something without realising.

Comment: This shouldnt be too much of a problem though. 
Are the changes to the aspx files or within the code(behind) itself?

Comment: Its likely that your web app is built as a single assembly. You may well be able to just deploy this single assembly, bit of a risk though. If you have the access you could try copying the site files, point a news IIS site at it and then deploy the web app assembly to to the bin folder of the app and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Well adding .. works..
working in .NET framework 2.0 with VS 2008 
I only pasted the complied dll of my web application that were in \bin folder + The file in which i had change wither aspx or aspx.cs ...

and this works .. it means you donot need to deploy full publish web application for covering up small bugs fixing in aspx.cs file